# NGINX - send body value to auth_request?

Tags: nginx

I need to somehow pass the POST request body (/oauth2) to the authorization request (/auth_subrequest), because it's contains the token I want to check in auth service.

I know that auth_request is GET with empty body, but I have no options - so I try to send $request_body as header or parameter, but with no success - auth service receives only empty strings.

At the same time I can see $request_body in first location log, and if I replace it with simple string - everything works fine, auth service starts to see it.

I would also like to avoid JS or Lua scripts, so as not to reduce the speed of the app under high load. Is this possible?

```
        location /oauth2 {
        access_log /dev/stdout custom; # -----> ok, body in log
        # add_header Custom 'valueeee'; -----> doesn't work at all
        # set $authBody "AuthBody"; -----> works fine
        set $authBody $request_body; # -----> doesn't work 

        auth_request /auth_subrequest;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://$some_backend$args;
    }

        location = /auth_subrequest {
        internal;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_connect_timeout 50;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";

        proxy_set_header Custom $authBody; # -----> empty if we use $request_body above
        set $args $args&custom_arg=$authBody; # -----> same
        proxy_pass http://$some_auth_service;
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 = @defaultResponse;
    }
```